# Am trying to upload a file to the database for a website am working on but am getting errors

Tags: php

The code:

```
<?php   
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Profile picture updated!";
            $picture_name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
            $image_info = explode(".", $picture_name);
            $rand = uniqid(true);
            $fileExt = strtolower(end($image_info));
            $picture_new_name =$rand."".".".$fileExt;
            $filepath="../images/".$picture_new_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$destination ="../imgs/$picture_new_name");
        }
      ?>
```

The error:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(../imgs/16085934f4e4d2.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\pages\Account.php on line 29

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "C:\xampp\tmp\php988A.tmp" to "../imgs/16085934f4e4d2.png" in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\pages\Account.php on line 29

Comment: The `../imgs` directory you are referencing there doesn't exists. You have to create it. Verify with `var_dump(file_exists('../imgs'), is_dir('../imgs'));` that it does indeed exists.

Comment: you define `$filepath="../images/".$picture_new_name;` but not use Are you sure it's  `../imgs/$picture_new_name"` your path

Answer (score 0):

Use correct filepath.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$filepath);
```